# How to scroll elements horizontally for a ListBox?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I have a ListBox, populate with some images in vertical position

```
[img]
[img]
[img]
```

I need an horizontal positioning like this instead

```
[img][img][img]
```

Any idea how to do it?

```
     <Custom:SurfaceListBox
        Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="FloorsSurfaceListBox"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        SelectionChanged="Floors_SelectionChanged"
        ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource FloorsListboxDataTemplate}"
        ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource SurfaceListBoxItemStyle}">
            <Custom:SurfaceListBox.OpacityMask>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.15"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.85"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Custom:SurfaceListBox.OpacityMask>
        </Custom:SurfaceListBox>




    <DataTemplate x:Key="FloorsListboxDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrlString}"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="{Binding Description,
                       FallbackValue='Description'}"
                       d:LayoutOverrides="Width"
                       FontFamily="/ClientWPF;component/Fonts/#Letter Gothic L"
                       Margin="0,100,0,40"
                       FontWeight="Normal">
                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderColorKey}}"/>
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the item's panel of your ListBox ([ItemsControl.ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) by an horizontal StackPanel.

```
<ListBox ...>
  ...
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of code? Thanks in advance

Comment: @GibboK That's the way to do it. Remove all the superfluous stuff in your code to make it works, then add them again one by one to find out what's breaking it.

Comment: @GibboK - I would suggest to use `VirtualizingStackPanel` instead of `StackPanel` to avoid loss of UI virtualization.